# Rails Tagging using Acts_As_Taggable_On: Finding All Tags in a Context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

In a blog system I'm working on, I want to use tags as a mechanism for deciding where a particular post shows up. I'm using acts_as_taggable_on to set up two contexts, the normal :tags context and then the :audience context.

I'm using an account model to tag the post  model like so:

```
account.tag(post, :with => "cat1, cat2", :on => :audience)
```

The problem I'm having is retrieving all the tags in a particular context. I'm able to get all the tags like so:

```
account.owned_tags # => "cat1, cat2, tag1", where tag1 came from the normal tag context
```

But what I'd like to do is just get the specific tags in a context, like this:

```
acount.owned_tags_on :audience
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`owned_tags` is normal `ActiveRecord` association:

```
has_many :owned_tags, :through => :owned_taggings, :source => :tag, :uniq => true
```

So you can perform `find` with conditions on it and select tags you need:

```
account.owned_tags.all(:conditions => ["context = ?", "audience"])
```

Comment: Sweet! That's perfect. Thanks!